# is $R^N_{ ++}$ a convex set?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Is $R^N_{ ++}$ a convex set?

I'm working on some optimization hw problems that have some functions of the type:
$f:\mathbb{R}^2_{++} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

And it seems like in general whenever $\mathbb{R}^N_{++}$ is your domain then, $\bigtriangledown f(x) = 0$ is not satisfied since you're unable to find $x$ values that satisfy that equality.

Could I say that this is true in general for any real valued funtions?

Comment: If by $\mathbb{R}^N_{++}$ you mean the n-tuples with positive (or non-negative) entries, then yes.

Comment: $f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-1)^2$ achieves $\nabla f(x)=0$ on $\mathbb{R}^n_{++}$. So I'm not sure how you came to your supposition that this can't happen.

Comment: If you prefer a function whose domain is naturally $\mathbb{R}^n_{++}$, then consider $f(x)=\sum_i x_i-\log x_i$.